# how to remove page link default menu of wordpress

Tags: wordpress, menu

when i created a page in word press then the page automatically added in default menu. what should i do to not show page link in default menu or how can i remove the link in default menu
.Is there any place in admin panel to manage the  default menu links.??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your own menu under Appearance->Menu AND then select Theme Location as your created menu. Let me know if u have any query.
Check image for reference-

[image]

You need to exclude pages from wp_nav_menu function in header.php file.
Following Link may be useful to you- [Follow Link](http://ehsanis.me/2010/11/30/wordpress-wp_nav_menu-to-exclude-pages/)

Comment: I don't want to create a new menu. A menu is already created(Wordpress default menu), How to remove a link of page from this menu